# Java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError on MacOS

Tags: java

I am trying to run an Java Applet application that ran fine on Windows XP (using Eclipse IDE) but after I imported the project on MacOS X (Using Eclipse on MacOS too), it fails to run displaying this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:675)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:316)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:280)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:374)
    at edu.isi.calo.mapping.gui.DieselUtil.(DieselUtil.java:9)
    at edu.isi.diesel.DieselEditor.processSettingsFile(DieselEditor.java:597)
    at edu.isi.diesel.DieselEditor.main(DieselEditor.java:80)`

Has anybody faced such a problem? I deleted all the class files and built the whole project again but it still pops up this runtime error.

Comment: Which version of OSX are you running and what version of Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that message is telling you is that your JRE does not know how to execute the class because the class has too new a version.  Two obvious questions are:

1. What version of the JRE do you have on Windows XP?
2. Do you have Apple's [latest distro of the JRE](http://developer.apple.com/java/), which is supposed to support Java 6?

I would guess that the version of the JRE you're using know is pre-Java 5.

Comment: -agree.  That Error happens when some class (maybe in a 3rd party Jar, not your code) was compiled with a newer JDK than what you are running.  It typically only happens for different major versions (1.4-1.5, 1.5-1.6, ...).

Comment: you can check the version by using the Java Preferences application on os X.

Comment: It helped me solve the problem! Thanks a lot :) Eclipse was using JRE 1.5 as default environment. Changing it to 1.6 solved the problem.